# Flutter gallery app is not able to runn

Tags: dart, flutter

I am trying to run the flutter gallery app and it is giving me the following issues:

Any idea on solving these issues is much appreciated. Tks.
[image]
[image]
 flutter doctor output

```
PS E:\Flutter_learning\flutter-dev\examples\flutter_gallery> flutter doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel beta, v0.3.2, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17134.48], locale en-SG)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK 27.0.3)
[√] Android Studio (version 3.1)
[√] VS Code, 64-bit edition (version 1.23.1)
[√] Connected devices (2 available)
```

Comment: What's the output of `flutter doctor`? Please add text instead of sceenshots. I guess the gallery needs to be updated.

Comment: I think you need to update your flutter SDK. Please paste `flutter doctor`

Comment: updated as requested.

Comment: @JackyBoi you have two connected devices.

Answer (score 2):

I switched the flutter channel to dev and then the app ran just fine...

Comment: strange,but worked for me as well. Not sure why it is not running on master and beta channels

Answer (score 0):

Comment out

```
 # flutter_goldens:
 #   sdk: flutter
```

and try again